# Protecting Devices from dd and fdisk Commands

Tags: linux, command-line, hard-disk, dd, fdisk

I'm wondering if there is some way to prevent certain certain devices from becoming the output file of the `dd` command and the target of the `fdisk` command. I'm currently using the two operations to set up a write a bootloader, kernel, and root filesystem on an SD card, which appears as `/dev/sdd`. I'm always a little anxious that I'll mix up `sdd` with `sdb`, or `sda` since the letters <kbd>A</kbd> and <kbd>D</kbd> are close on the keyboard, and I would like to find a way to prevent commands with this format:

```
dd if=/dev/sd[a-zA-Z0-9]* of=/dev/sd[ab]
```

or

```
fdisk /dev/sd[ab]
```

Comment: One possible solution is to setup permissions so that you only have direct write access to SD-card but not on any other storage device.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might try writing a udev rule to give the supplemental HDD(s) sufficiently unique names.

Another idea: Whenever you can phrase a security requirement as "It's not who's doing it, it's how they're doing it" you're talking about type enforcement, and in most Linux distros TE is done at the MAC level. Most of my MAC experience is with "SELinux"

You can't lock it down at the DAC level otherwise you wouldn't be able to perform I/O on the device (not necessarily a failing of DAC as a security model, it's just current DAC policy is solely identity based so all programs running under a particular identity get identical rights with no additional administrative expression possible). Locking it down at the MAC level can be made so that regular user space components can't do anything with the block file but your root utilities and certain parts of the platform can. On Fedora this is already kind of the case with block devices showing up with the SELinux type of `fixed_disk_device_t` and grub having `bootloader_exec_t` see the following example:

```
[root@localhost ~]# ls -lhZ $(which grub2-install)
-rwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:bootloader_exec_t:s0 /sbin/grub2-install
[root@localhost ~]# ls -lhZ /dev/sda
brw-rw----+ root disk system_u:object_r:fixed_disk_device_t:s0 /dev/sda
[root@localhost ~]# sesearch --allow | egrep bootloader | grep fixed
   allow bootloader_t fixed_disk_device_t : lnk_file { read getattr } ; 
   allow bootloader_t fixed_disk_device_t : chr_file { ioctl read write getattr lock append open } ; 
   allow bootloader_t fixed_disk_device_t : blk_file { ioctl read write getattr lock append open } ; 
[root@localhost ~]#
```

Whereas `dd` has a regular bin_t label:

```
[root@localhost ~]# ls -lhZ $(which dd)
-rwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:bin_t:s0       /bin/dd
```

`bin_t` (apparently) can still write to block devices but creating a new file context type for `fdisk` and `dd` and writing an selinux rule to disallow the new type from accessing `fixed_disk_device_t` shouldn't be too difficult. You would just need to make it so regular user roles can't do it but users with the `sysadm_t` can do it, then remember to just do a `newrole -r root:sysadm_r` before you try to re-partition the disk or do a `dd` over the block device (which shouldn't be a huge deal since it's not like you run `fdisk` every day all day long).

Probably more work than you were looking for, but TE is the mechanism that solves the general problem you're running into. Personally, the `udev` rule is probably you're safest bet. I only mention the TE stuff in case you're interested in solving a larger set of problems similar to this one.

Answer (score 4):

If you are unsure about `/dev/sdx`, use the alternative device names you can find in `/dev/disk/`.

For example, my SD card reader is `/dev/disk/by-id/usb-TS-RDF5_SD_Transcend_000000000011-0:0`. That's a bit verbose, for sure, but at least there is no way to confuse it with a HDD.

Alternatively a `hdparm -i /dev/sdx` may show useful info if it's a hard disk and help avoid unfortunate accidents...

Comment: Is it possible to create a uniquely named link to a device?

Comment: With udev rules, but it will work only on boxes that use those rules (and not when booting a Live CD or similar), whereas `/dev/disk/*` is available on any Linux system.

Comment: udev rules will accomplish this, but it's easier to use symbolic links (so long as the "from" link isn't itself in /dev, /proc, or /run) OR simply make a variable (as in bash/zsh): `mysdcard=/dev/sdd`, and then you of course just use `$mysdcard` as the argument wherever you need it.

Answer (score 3):

There are longer, meaningful names in `/dev/disk/by-*`. For a whole disk, `/dev/disk/by-id` contains a symlink to the disk device that contains the disk model and serial number.

For additional protection, give yourself the permission to access the device (e.g. `sudo chown sj755 /dev/disk/by-id/ata-Yoyodine-50RDF15H`), then do the rest under your own user instead of root.

Make sure to double-check that the disk you're going to act on has the expected content, e.g. check `fdisk -l /dev/whatever`, `file - </dev/sdz99`, … In the shell, <kbd>Esc</kbd> <kbd>.</kbd> to recall the argument of the previous command, never retype the device name.

Answer (score 1):

I see two ways to accomplish that:

1. Write a wrapper (shell function) and check the arguments there before passing them to the real program.
2. Do these operations from a shell which has been restricted by SELinux, AppArmor or the like.